# Cards in Boxes Problem - Expected value from transition matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a large number of boxes each containing a baseball card.  There are six unique types of cards that the child can collect.  Define $\{X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots\}$ to be random variables that represent the number of unique types of cards found up to box $0,1,2,\dots$

As this is a Markov chain, I have defined the transition matrix
$$P(i,j) = \left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
1- \frac{i}{6} &: j = i+1 \\
\frac{i}{6} &: j = i \\
0 &: \text{Otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.$$
For $i,j \in \{0,\dots,6\}$.

I need to show that the expected number of baseball cards after opening $k$ boxes follows $E(k) = (5\cdot E(k-1)+6)/6$, but am unsure as to how to get the expected value from the transition matrix above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of reaching state $i$ after $k$ boxes are opened are in the first row of matrix $P^k$. If we think in terms of the matrix multiplication $P^k=P^{k-1}\cdot P$, we see that the entry in row $0$, column $i$ of $P^k$ is (with row and column numbers starting from $0$ to match the state numbers):

$$P_{0,i}^k = \dfrac{i}{6} P_{0,i}^{k-1} + \left(1-\dfrac{i-1}{6} \right)P_{0,i-1}^{k-1}\qquad\qquad\text{(where $P_{0,-1}^{k-1}$ is defined as $0$)}.$$

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(k) &=& \sum_{i=0}^{6}{iP_{0,i}^k} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{6}{i \left[\dfrac{i}{6} P_{0,i}^{k-1} + \left(1-\dfrac{i-1}{6} \right) P_{0,i-1}^{k-1} \right]} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{6}{P_{0,i}^{k-1} \left[\dfrac{i^2}{6} + \left(i+1 \right)\left(1-\dfrac{i}{6} \right) \right]} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{6}{P_{0,i}^{k-1} \left[1 + \dfrac{5i}{6} \right]} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{6}{P_{0,i}^{k-1} } + \dfrac{5}{6}\sum_{i=0}^{6}{iP_{0,i}^{k-1} } \\
&=& 1 + \dfrac{5}{6}E(k-1) \qquad\text{ as required.}
\end{eqnarray*}